# Add class attribute with decorator

Tags: javascript, babeljs, decorator, ecmascript-next

I try to use a decorator to add some method or property to an annotated class.

This is my decorator :

```
export default function Component(params) {
    return function decorator(target) {
        target.template = params.template;
        console.log(target, params.template);
    }
}
```

I used it this way :

```
@Component({
    template: template
})
export default class App {}
```

But when I use this class :

```
app.template // undefined;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Decorators are a *proposal* (i.e. experimental). They are not part of ES6 or any other version of the language.

Comment: Yeah i not that. It's a miss spelling. But you not help me :)

Comment: *"But you not help me"* Well, now you will be able to use the right context when talking about decorators, and others will know what you mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying class object itself, i.e.

```
App.template // your template is here
```

and you just defined a static property for App class in this case.

In order to set template for class instances you should use:

```
target.prototype.template = params.template;
```

(Good example that classes are actually just syntactical sugar over constructor functions and prototype-based inheritance).

Also, I think [this article](http://raganwald.com/2015/06/26/decorators-in-es7.html) about combining mixins and decorators might be helpful.

Comment: I don't know  why i haven't think to this before. Thank this is the solution. I already read this article. But i don't understand how i can pass parameter to a mixin?